# Calculate summation of the function

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a array list of points like
A[] = {2,5,2,25,84}
I have calculated A' as Σ((Ai) / n ), where n is number of datasets
I have to calculate
Σ(Ai-A¯)²
How do I do it using java Streams?

like for the above example A¯ will be (2+5+2+25+84) / 5 which comes out to be 23.6. then by next formula it will be (2-23.6)²+(5-23.6)²+(2-23.6)²+(25-23.6)²+(84-23.6)²

Like to calculate A¯
we can write

```
Integer Asum = A
            .stream()
            .reduce((prev, next) -> prev + next)
            .get();
```

we got summation of all elements, then we can write

```
 A¯ = Asum/n
```

so how to do that for Σ(Ai-A¯)²

Comment: @Deadpool like for the above example A¯ will be (2+5+2+25+84) / 5 which comes out to be 23.6. then by next formula it will be (2-23.6)²+(5-23.6)²+(2-23.6)²+(25-23.6)²+(84-23.6)²

Comment: What have you written/tried? Is this a homework assignment? 
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ajaysingh welcome to stackoverflow, can you provide the code and tell us where you need the help with. At the moment its too broad and difficult to figure out what you need

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider yes, but I can solve it using normal for loops, but I am thinking how can i optimize it and use streams. The first part i can use streams, but for second part I am getting confused, should i use multiple streams which could be easy, but can it be done in a single stream function

Comment: Streams aren't necessarily likely to "optimize" anything.

Comment: _"I am thinking how can i optimize it and use streams"_ -- Using streams isn't the same as optimizing.  Often, normal for-loops are the best choice, because they're easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is to make use of `map` operation along with a `sum` terminal operation such as in the following block of code:

```
final int[] a = {2, 5, 2, 25, 84};
double averageOfA = (double) Arrays.stream(a).sum() / a.length; // A¯ in question
// System.out.println(averageOfA); // prints 23.6
double sumOfA = Arrays.stream(a)
            .mapToDouble(num -> Math.pow(num - averageOfA, 2)) // mapping here
            .sum(); // sum of all such values 
// System.out.println(sumOfA); // prints 4929.2
```